# Difference between two revision of bluetooth profile

Tags: bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I want to know the exact difference between bluetooth profile HFP_1.6 and HFP_1.7 revision.From where I will get these difference.

Is there any section in the document of HFP specs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the new adapted Bluetooth spec template, you may can not find the different between v1.7.1(the latest) and the v1.6.

However, you can find the main feature difference for the Table 3.1 -Application layer procedures. this table described the main features for each HFP version, e.g. you can find v1.6 added WBS(and codec negotiation) and Individual Indicator Activation features, and v1.7 added "HF Indicators" than v1.6. That's the main difference.